# Removing JFrame Border?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, border

I have a Java Swing GUI and everything in my JFrame is offset by a few pixels. On MacOS, I had to offset everything by 12 pixels downward to account for it. On Windows, everything is shifted to the left and downward as well. I discovered that

```
setUndecorated(true);
```

removes the JFrame border (which I suspect is the cause of my problems) but it also removes the title bar.
Is there a way I can remove the JFrame border (or some other alternative to make sure everything is centered) and still keep the title bar? I need the title bar so that I can move the JFrame around and have the maximize/minimize/close functions.

Also, the layout is set to null in case that matters. (Everything I'm doing is pixel - based so I cannot set it to anything else).

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy way to accomplish this. The default system LookAndFeel's title bar and window borders are drawn by the system. I have not messed with Swing in a while, but I suppose you can create a LookAndFeel which mimics the system's, but without borders. I am not really sure.

Comment: *the layout is set to null in case that matters* - yes that matters. Swing was designed to be used with layout manager. You should not be using a null layout. If you are doing custom painting all the painting should be done on a JPanel and you add the JPanel to the frame. Then all the painting will be relative to the panel, whether the frame has a border of not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after Googling a bit more. Calling

```
getContentPane().setPreferredSize(...)
pack();
```

inside the JFrame constructor will adjust everything so that the titlebar and borders will not impact the view of the content pane.
For anyone else that may need this, you have to set the preferred size of the content pane specifically as that is what you want to appear correctly.

This way you can keep the titlebar and all the normal functionality of a JFrame window that you would otherwise lose with setUndecorated(true);.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are adding 12px is because this is consume by the Title and border.
If you use `setUndecorated(true)` You will loose the title bar and you have to implement the addWindowListener to add a location changing of of an application.
The best way to do is:

```
Class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      //JFrame
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      //Create a Main Panel and setPreferred Size and not set Size or set Bound
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(); //You value down
      mainPanel.setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(x, y));
      frame.add(mainPanel);

      //and then in last add
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      //the pack method help you to setSize of the JFrame According to the             
      //Component size
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```